# Fast csv import

Tags: matlab, csv, import-from-csv, file-import

I wish to import a large number of csv files to MATLAB. I can do this without any difficulty except it takes a lot of time - about 3 seconds per file with the following code. Is there a way to do it faster? Here `A` is a matrix with 15 rows and 250 columns. There are 150 files.

```
tic

file_name = [];
for w = scenario_size:-1:1
    file_name = sprintf('monthly_population_%d.csv',w) ; % read file name f
    A = xlsread(file_name);                
    pop(:,:,w) = A' ; 
end
clear A
toc
```

Comment: if your `.csv` files are uniformly formatted, I think the fastest way to read them will be using `tesxscan` or `fscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

You may have improved performance by using readmatrix, instead of xlsread.  For example:

```
A = readmatrix(file_name);
```

Or, if you are on a Matlab release which doesn't have readmatrix, try readtable:

```
A = table2array(readtable(file_name));
```

Comment: `readmatrix` was introduced in R2019a. For older versions, use `csvread`.